# convert a list of dataframe into another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list, numpy

Code:

```
from datetime import date
from datetime import timedelta
from nsepy import get_history
import pandas as pd


end1 = date.today()
start1 = end1 - timedelta(days=25)
exp_date1 = date(2022,8,25)
exp_date2 = date(2022,9,29)

# stock = ['HDFCLIFE']
stock = ['RELIANCE','HDFCBANK','INFY','ICICIBANK','HDFC','TCS','KOTAKBANK','LT','SBIN','HINDUNILVR','AXISBANK',
         'ITC','BAJFINANCE','BHARTIARTL','ASIANPAINT','HCLTECH','MARUTI','TITAN','BAJAJFINSV','TATAMOTORS',
         'TECHM','SUNPHARMA','TATASTEEL','M&M','WIPRO','ULTRACEMCO','POWERGRID','HINDALCO','NTPC','NESTLEIND',
         'GRASIM','ONGC','JSWSTEEL','HDFCLIFE','INDUSINDBK','SBILIFE','DRREDDY','ADANIPORTS','DIVISLAB','CIPLA',
         'BAJAJ-AUTO','TATACONSUM','UPL','BRITANNIA','BPCL','EICHERMOT','HEROMOTOCO','COALINDIA','SHREECEM','IOC']

target_stocks = []
# oi_change = []
for stock in stock:
    stock_jan = get_history(symbol=stock,
                        start=start1,
                        end=end1,
                        futures=True,
                        expiry_date=exp_date1)
    stock_feb = get_history(symbol=stock,
                        start=start1,
                        end=end1,
                        futures=True,
                        expiry_date=exp_date2)
    delivery_per_age = get_history(symbol=stock,
                               start=start1,
                               end=end1)
    symbol_s = get_history(symbol=stock,
                       start=start1,
                       end=end1)
    oi_combined = pd.concat([stock_jan['Change in OI'] + stock_feb['Change in OI']])
    total_oi = pd.concat([stock_jan['Open Interest']+stock_feb['Open Interest']])
    delivery_vol = pd.concat([delivery_per_age['Deliverable Volume']])
    # delivery_per = pd.concat([delivery_per_age['%Deliverble']*100])
    na_me = pd.concat([symbol_s['Symbol']])
    close = pd.concat([delivery_per_age['Close']])
    df = pd.DataFrame(na_me)
    df['TOTAL_OPN_INT'] = total_oi
    df['OI_COMBINED'] = oi_combined
    df['%_CHANGE'] = ((df['OI_COMBINED'] / df['TOTAL_OPN_INT']) * 100).__round__(2)
    df['AVG_OI_COMBINED'] = df['OI_COMBINED'].rolling(5).mean()
    # df['DELIVERY_VOL'] = delivery_vol
    # df['AVG_DELIVERY_VOL'] = df['DELIVERY_VOL'].rolling(5).mean()
    # df['DELIVERY_PER'] = delivery_per
    # df['AVG_DELIVERY_%'] = df['DELIVERY_PER'].rolling(5).mean()
    df['_CLOSE_PRICE_'] = close
    pd.set_option('display.max_columns',8)
    pd.set_option('display.width',200)
    # print(df)

    cond = ((df.loc[df.index[-5:-1], '%_CHANGE'].agg(min) > 0) |(df.loc[df.index[-6:-1], '%_CHANGE'].agg(min) > 0)) & (df.loc[df.index[-1], '%_CHANGE'] < 0)
    if(cond):
        target_stocks.append(df)
print(target_stocks)
```

**PRODUCT:**

```
[                Symbol  TOTAL_OPN_INT  OI_COMBINED  %_CHANGE  AVG_OI_COMBINED  _CLOSE_PRICE_
Date                                                                                        
2022-07-19  HINDUNILVR        1015800       313200     30.83              NaN        2567.95
2022-07-20  HINDUNILVR        1617900       602100     37.21              NaN        2604.50
2022-07-21  HINDUNILVR        2355000       737100     31.30              NaN        2607.45
2022-07-22  HINDUNILVR        3671400      1316400     35.86              NaN        2640.60
2022-07-25  HINDUNILVR        5421300      1749900     32.28         943740.0        2623.60
2022-07-26  HINDUNILVR        6886200      1464900     21.27        1174080.0        2547.10
2022-07-27  HINDUNILVR        8522700      1636500     19.20        1380960.0        2581.95
2022-07-28  HINDUNILVR       10300200      1777500     17.26        1589040.0        2620.10
2022-07-29  HINDUNILVR       10250100       -50100     -0.49        1315740.0        2637.40
2022-08-01  HINDUNILVR       10237200       -12900     -0.13         963180.0        2593.00
2022-08-02  HINDUNILVR       10178700       -58500     -0.57         658500.0        2635.25
2022-08-03  HINDUNILVR       10208400        29700      0.29         337140.0        2626.35
2022-08-04  HINDUNILVR       10289700        81300      0.79          -2100.0        2627.95
2022-08-05  HINDUNILVR       10334100        44400      0.43          16800.0        2645.40
2022-08-08  HINDUNILVR       10350000        15900      0.15          22560.0        2650.35
2022-08-10  HINDUNILVR       10422900        72900      0.70          48840.0        2642.80
2022-08-11  HINDUNILVR       10432800         9900      0.09          44880.0        2613.70
2022-08-12  HINDUNILVR       10378200       -54600     -0.53          17700.0        2594.95]
```

Process finished with exit code 0.

`Problem:`
When I ran the code on 12-aug I got this output as displayed above which is a list. So how can I convert that list of target_stocks into pandas dataframe.
when I tried using `df2 = pd.Dataframe(target_stocks)` it is throwing an error must pass 2-d input. shape(4,18,16).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are appending a dataframe to an empty list. This method does not work for dataframes. Instead of having `target_stocks = []` make it `target_stocks = pd.DataFrame()` (an empty dataframe). Then change:

```py
if(cond):
    target_stocks.append(df)
```

to

```py
if(cond):
    target_stocks = pd.concat([target_stocks, df])
```

To add a blank row at the end of the dataframe if the condition is met, add the code below. This finds the length of your data frame and adds a blank row (created by placing an empty value in every column):

```
target_stocks.loc[len(target_stocks)]=['']*len(target_stocks.columns)
```

All together:

```py
from datetime import date
from datetime import timedelta
from nsepy import get_history
import pandas as pd

end1 = date.today()
start1 = end1 - timedelta(days=25)
exp_date1 = date(2022,8,25)
exp_date2 = date(2022,9,29)

# stock = ['HDFCLIFE']
stock = ['RELIANCE','HDFCBANK','INFY','ICICIBANK','HDFC','TCS','KOTAKBANK','LT','SBIN','HINDUNILVR','AXISBANK',
         'ITC','BAJFINANCE','BHARTIARTL','ASIANPAINT','HCLTECH','MARUTI','TITAN','BAJAJFINSV','TATAMOTORS',
         'TECHM','SUNPHARMA','TATASTEEL','M&M','WIPRO','ULTRACEMCO','POWERGRID','HINDALCO','NTPC','NESTLEIND',
         'GRASIM','ONGC','JSWSTEEL','HDFCLIFE','INDUSINDBK','SBILIFE','DRREDDY','ADANIPORTS','DIVISLAB','CIPLA',
         'BAJAJ-AUTO','TATACONSUM','UPL','BRITANNIA','BPCL','EICHERMOT','HEROMOTOCO','COALINDIA','SHREECEM','IOC']

target_stocks = pd.DataFrame()
# oi_change = []
for stock in stock:
    stock_jan = get_history(symbol=stock,
                        start=start1,
                        end=end1,
                        futures=True,
                        expiry_date=exp_date1)
    stock_feb = get_history(symbol=stock,
                        start=start1,
                        end=end1,
                        futures=True,
                        expiry_date=exp_date2)
    delivery_per_age = get_history(symbol=stock,
                               start=start1,
                               end=end1)
    symbol_s = get_history(symbol=stock,
                       start=start1,
                       end=end1)
    oi_combined = pd.concat([stock_jan['Change in OI'] + stock_feb['Change in OI']])
    total_oi = pd.concat([stock_jan['Open Interest']+stock_feb['Open Interest']])
    delivery_vol = pd.concat([delivery_per_age['Deliverable Volume']])
    # delivery_per = pd.concat([delivery_per_age['%Deliverble']*100])
    na_me = pd.concat([symbol_s['Symbol']])
    close = pd.concat([delivery_per_age['Close']])
    df = pd.DataFrame(na_me)
    df['TOTAL_OPN_INT'] = total_oi
    df['OI_COMBINED'] = oi_combined
    df['%_CHANGE'] = ((df['OI_COMBINED'] / df['TOTAL_OPN_INT']) * 100).__round__(2)
    df['AVG_OI_COMBINED'] = df['OI_COMBINED'].rolling(5).mean()
    # df['DELIVERY_VOL'] = delivery_vol
    # df['AVG_DELIVERY_VOL'] = df['DELIVERY_VOL'].rolling(5).mean()
    # df['DELIVERY_PER'] = delivery_per
    # df['AVG_DELIVERY_%'] = df['DELIVERY_PER'].rolling(5).mean()
    df['_CLOSE_PRICE_'] = close
    pd.set_option('display.max_columns',8)
    pd.set_option('display.width',200)
    # print(df)

    cond = ((df.loc[df.index[-5:-1], '%_CHANGE'].agg(min) > 0) |(df.loc[df.index[-6:-1], '%_CHANGE'].agg(min) > 0)) & (df.loc[df.index[-1], '%_CHANGE'] < 0)
    if(cond):
        target_stocks = pd.concat([target_stocks, df])
        target_stocks.loc[len(target_stocks)]=['']*len(target_stocks.columns)
target_stocks
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: It is giving correct output but suppose there are 4 to 5 stocks then there is no blank row between the each stock data as it was there earlier. Due to this it is going tough to separate and analyse each stock. so plz provide code for this problem also

Comment: Sure. Check the edit.

Comment: yes......it is giving correct output.......thank you.